# Does the Relative density of water change based on the state it is in

Tags: gravity, water, density

Will [Relative density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_density) of water change based on the state it is in? Ie solid, liquid, gas.

What causes this change(if any) in Rd?

Comment: You should be aware that use of "relative density" is much less common than "specific gravity" for describing this concept.

Comment: @dmckee: The Wiki articles states that the use of relative density is preferred :)

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_water for info on the density of water and ice. The density of steam is pressure and temperature dependant.

Comment: @Bernhard: It might be "preferred", but the actual use on the ground is driven by history and habit.

Comment: This was a more brief way of saying is the specific gravity of solid(frozen) water relative to the specific gravity of liquid water different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the density of water changes with temperature in a non-linear way (which is important if you want life on your planet).

It has a maximum density at 4deg C and is unusual in that it expands (lower density) as a solid - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_(properties)#Density_of_water_and_ice

As a gas it's density varies with temperature and pressure like any other gas.